# why there are two other view exist when use storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

my Xcode version is 5.1.1.
i create a new project using the Single View Application template,and add a UIButton on it then run it, in this method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        NSLog(@"%@", [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]);
}
```

the log is :

```
*<UIWindow:0x750fa10>
|   *<UIView:0x7962b20>
|   |   *<UIView:0x7962c60>
|   |   *<UIView:0x79621c0>
|   |   *<UIRoundedRectButton:0x7618430> - AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT
|   |   |   <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground:0x7618e70>
|   |   |   <UIImageView:0x7619560>
|   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x761a920>
```

there are two view.

if i override it in here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

the log is :

```
<UIWindow:0x8301700>
|   <UIView:0x10c03350>
|   |   <UIRoundedRectButton:0x10c036f0>
|   |   |   <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground:0x10c04080>
|   |   |   <UIImageView:0x10c048e0>
|   |   |   <UIButtonLabel:0x10c05cc0>
```

there is no view here.
what happend? does the Auto Layout mechanism do something？

Comment: What is exactly what you are asking?

Comment: why there are two additional views when use the storyboard

Comment: Is there a navigation controller in storyboard maybe that is showing up.